# How to display data on separate rows in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

I have a table with the following setup

```
ID            InOut_Status     InOut_Datetime
1             IN               9/12/2017 8:00
2             IN               9/12/2017 10:00
1             OUT              9/12/2017 1:00
2             OUT              9/12/2017 3:00
```

I want to be able to see both status and date on the same row vs separate rows for example

```
ID        In_Status    In_Datetime            Out_Status      Out_Datetime
1         IN           9/12/2017 8:00         OUT             9/12/2017 1:00
2         IN           9/12/2017 10:00        OUT             9/12/2017 3:00
```

I would like to return all columns.  I just provided a few for example.  I also would like to show only the most recent `Datetime` for each `ID` and if the user hasn't checked out, I would like for the `Out_Datetime` to be blank.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to return all columns"? Are there more columns than the five shown (`ID`, `In_Status`, `In_Datetime`, `Out_Status`, `Out_Datetime`)? Are there other statuses apart from `IN` and `OUT`?

Comment: There are multiple columns.  I just provided the three columns in the first table for example.  There are no other statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self join:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT ins.id
  , ins.InOut_Datetime as in_time
  , outs.InOut_Datetime as out_time
  , row_number() over (partition by ins.id order by ins.InOut_Datetime desc) as ranking
FROM table ins
LEFT JOIN table outs
    ON ins.id = outs.id
    AND outs.InOut_Status = 'OUT'
    AND outs.InOut_Datetime > ins.InOut_Datetime
WHERE ins.InOut_Status = 'IN'
and ins.InOut_Datetime >  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
) t
WHERE t.ranking = 1
```

Updated query to :

get logins within last 24 hours

get the latest login of a user only

show out time only if it's later than in time

Comment: Jon, Could you include the row_number in your query?  Also, since each user has multiple in and out times, when I run the query, some of the out times will be earlier than the in times.  The IN time should be earlier the out times.  I'm displaying the data within the last 24 hours so the Out time should only show the times they checked out within 24 hours after the In time and blank if they haven't checked out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to left join, however, you want to limit the join to the first record returned in descending order using a sub query.

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,InOut_Status,InOutDateTime,
            CheckOutInstanceDescending = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClockOut.ID ORDER BY ClockOut.InOutDateTime DESC)
        FROM
            MyTable ClockIn
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable ClockOut ON ClockOut.ID=ClockIn.ID
        WHERE
            ClockIn.InOut_Status='IN'
    )AS Combined
    WHERE
        Combined.CheckOutInstanceDescending=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple pivot would fix this the easiest: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx.  You can run this in SSMS 2008 or higher(I wrote it in SQL 2016).

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id INT, InOut_Status VARCHAR(8), InOut_Datetime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Temp (Id, InOut_Status, InOut_Datetime) VALUES (1, 'IN', '9-12-2017 8:00'), (2, 'IN', '9-12-2017 10:00'),(1, 'OUT', '9-12-2017 13:00'),(2, 'OUT', '9-12-2017 16:00'),(3, 'IN', '9-12-2017 06:00')


SELECT
   pvt.Id
, 'IN' AS In_Status
, pvt.[In]
, 'OUT' AS Out_Status
, pvt.OUT
From @Temp
PIVOT(MAX(InOut_Datetime) FOR InOut_Status IN ([In], [OUT])) AS pvt
```